# What to do if error TS2304: Cannot find name 'before' ocures

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am trying to implement some cypress tests for work and I am getting the error above:  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'. i am new to cypress and dont really know what to do with this, the command in the before does work but affterwards in the tests it gives an error.

```
describe('Qualifications List Overview', () => {

  before ( () => {
    navigateToSite('#/management/qualification');
  });



  it('should open Qualification Table', () => {
   QualificationList
     .displayQualificationTable();


  });

  it('should navigate to Qualifiation edit modal, check values and close modal', () => {
    QualificationList
      .openQualificationEditModal()
      .checkCurrentQualificationValues()
      .closeQualificationModal();
  });



});
```

Methods QualifiationList

```
    export class QualificationList {



  static displayQualificationTable() {
    return cy.get('#management-qualification--')
      .should('be.visible')
      .get('datatable-body-row')
      .should('have.length.greaterThan', 0);
  }

  static openQualificationEditModal() {
    cy.get('#QualificationUpdate')
      .first()
      .should('not.be.empty')
      .click({force: true})
      .wait(2000);
    return this;
  }

  static checkCurrentQualificationValues() {
    cy.get('#Qualification Name')
      .invoke('val')
      .should('not.be.empty')
      .get('id')
      .invoke('val')
      .should('not.be.empty');
    return this;
  }

  static closeQualificationModal() {
    cy.get('button')
      .contains('Cancel')
      .click();
    return this;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that jumps out between your code and [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Hooks) is that you are using arrow functions. That can cause this type of problem, because `this` is handled differently. Try not using arrow functions.

Comment: what would be the alternative? I kind of do not know pretty much new to cypress

Comment: I just changed it to function like in the doku but it still gives me the same error